# Kendo MultiSelect does not populate bound values

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a `MultiSelect` belongs to Kendo `ListView` EditorTemplates. When I want to submit selected `MultiSelect` values, I got list of items selected, but all populated with 0 value. I cant get correct value of selected items.

Here is my ListView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<esCMS.Modules.C2C.Domain.c2cFieldRangeList>()
  .Name("listView")
  .TagName("div")
  .ClientTemplateId("template")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.FieldRangeID))
      .PageSize(6)
      .Create(create => create.Action("AddRange", "Field"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateRange", "Field"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("ReadRange", "Field", new { id = Model.FieldID }))
  ))
```

And here is my EditorTemplates:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RangeValue)
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RangeValue, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width:180px" })
        <span data-for="RangeValue" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedValues)
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x=> x.SelectedValues)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:180px" })
            .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.Fields, "FieldID", "Title")))
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

**Edit:** `ViewBag.Fields` contains List of `c2cFieldList` model and I expect to get List of `FieldID` when I submit view.

```
ViewBag.Fields = Entities.c2cField.Where(x => !x.IsGeneral && !x.IsTemp).Select(x => new c2cFieldList { Title = x.Title, FieldID = x.FieldID});
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DataTextField/DataValueField settings for the multiselect control?

Comment: Yes I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: What is contained within your ViewBags.Fields collection and the datatype of the items? what are you expecting to be posted back?

Comment: I updated my post, have a look.

Comment: What is the data type of the fieldID? Is it a guid/string/int/ other?

Comment: It is `IEnumerable<int>`. I inspected select element of dropdown wrapped by kendo stuffs. Values for options are there. But I get nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64744/discussion-between-david-shorthose-and-saber-amani).